# php array wont display right in table

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array that I’m trying to display in 4 rows of 5 but it won’t display right. With the code I have it displayed like

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>...
</tr>
</table>
```

instead of

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The test code I’m using is given below. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
$field = 0; 
echo "<table><tbody>";
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxx");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT item_id FROM user_item");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
{
if ($field % 5 == 0) echo '<tr>'; 
echo '<td><img src="img/items/'. intval($row["item_id"]). '.png"></td>'; 
if ($field % 5 == 4) echo '</tr>'; 
$field++; 
}
if ($field % 5 != 0) echo '</tr>'; 
echo "</tbody></table>";
}
// <img src="img/items/'. intval($sprite). '.png">
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: any reason you've got two `{` at the start of the while loop?

Comment: sorry did not realize i had done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    if ($field % 5 == 0)
        echo '<tr>';

    echo '<td><img src="img/items/'. intval($row["item_id"]). '.png"></td>';

    if ($field % 5 == 4)
    {
        echo '</tr>';
        $field = 0;
    }
    else
        $field++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($field % 5 != 0) echo '</tr>'; 

echo "</tbody></table>";
```

should be outside the while loop.

cause end table should not be in the loop. (repeated)
and as important you are prematurely terminating the row.